# saltstack apply state receiving error

Tags: command-line-interface, state, salt-stack

I am trying to apply a state on saltstack master.  I am using this command but receiving this error:

```
salt '*' state.apply filename setenv: dev
```

Error from command:

> No minions match the target.  No command was sent, no jid was assigned.

Does anyone know the right command, I am just updating a configuration in aws environment.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and post code snippets? I can't help you because your situation is unclear to me.

Comment: yes;  I have updated a state on the master server and trying to push the update for IAM users to aws IAM users.  I am using this command format:     salt '*' state.apply filename setenv: dev

Answer (score 2):

The `state.apply` module will call `state.highstate` or `state.sls` based on the arguments. To apply individual SLS files, pass them as a comma-separated list. By looking at your command you are trying to apply the SLS file called `filename`. In order to make my answer more clearly in the examples I will use `test` as the SLS file.

If you would like to specify the salt fileserver environment to be used when applying states from the command line your command be:

```
salt '*' state.apply test saltenv=dev
```

If no `saltenv` is specified, the minion config will be checked for an `environment` parameter and if found, it will be used. If none is found, `base` will be used!

In order to test if any minion matches the target you could use the `test.ping` module:

```
salt '*' test.ping
```

Note that the target (`'*'`) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have any salt-minions keys accepted on the salt master thus, there are no minions returning when targeting all minions (wildcard: *).

Make sure your salt minion is able to communicate to the salt master.

To test from the salt-master run:

```
salt '*' test.ping
```

To check the key acceptance status run:

```
salt-key
```

to accept a key:

```
salt-key -a "insert minion name here"
```

to remove a key:

```
salt-key -d "insert minion name here"
```